# How to More Efficiently Load Parquet Files in Spark (pySpark v1.2.0)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, parquet

I'm loading in high-dimensional parquet files but only need a few columns. My current code looks like:

```
dat = sqc.parquetFile(path) \
          .filter(lambda r: len(r.a)>0) \
          .map(lambda r: (r.a, r.b, r.c))
```

My mental model of what's happening is that it's loading in all the data, then throwing out the columns I don't want. I'd obviously prefer it to not even read in those columns, and from what I understand about parquet that seems to be possible.

So there are two questions:

1. Is my mental model wrong? Or is the spark compiler smart enough to only read in columns a, b, and c in the example above?
2. How can I force `sqc.parquetFile()` to read in data more efficiently?

Comment: I think your chances to get  read only needed columns will be higher if you `map` _before_ `filter`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Spark DataFrame API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#dataframe-operations

Something like

```
dat.select("a", "b", "c").filter(lambda r: len(r.a)>0)
```

Or you can use Spark SQL:

```
dat.regiserTempTable("dat")
sqc.sql("select a, b, c from dat where length(a) > 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark always do things in a lazy way, using a native scala feature. The scala code is already compiled, and it make runtime smart, I mean lazy, decisions. With parquet, it should only read the necessary data, referenced by the code. Of course that depends on the structure of the particular parquet file. The point is that it will take advantage of the columnar format. I don't know enough about Python, but it should be able to do the same thing. Maybe check if the pyspark Row class uses some sort of lazy magic. One quick way to verify is to do a controlled experiment, write another rdd operation that reference more fields, but doesn't ouput them. Then you can just compare the wall clock time difference between the 2 operations. Depending on some relevant details of the underlying parquet file, you may not see the difference even it does lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will only selected fields from Disk.

" opens all the data files, but only reads the portion of each file containing the values for that column. The column values are stored consecutively, minimizing the I/O required to process the values within a single column."

This documentation is for impala, i think reading logic is same for spark too http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_parquet.html#parquet_data_files_unique_1